# call of overloaded ‘func(char*&)’ is ambiguous

Tags: c++

I'm writing my own operating system, so i wrote a printf implementation. i split the code into 2 files:
coolio.h:

```
#ifndef __COOLOS__COOLIO_H
#define __COOLOS__COOLIO_H

namespace coolOS{
    namespace common{
        void printf(char* str);
        void printfHex(char bit);
    }
}
#endif
```

and coolio.cpp:

```
#include<common/coolio.h>
using namespace coolOS::common;

void printf(char* str){
    //printf implementation
}
void printfHex(char key){
    char * msg = "00";
    //converts key and puts it in msg
    printf(msg);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error: call of overloaded ‘printf(char*&)’ is ambiguous
```

It seems like the im some how overloading the printf function instead of implementing it...

Comment: Note that it's UB to modify `char *msg = "00";`. You want `char msg[] = "00";` instead.

Comment: This doesn't address the problem, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__COOLOS__COOLIO_H`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: I know they are reserved, but since I am writing an operating system and a standard library this code is the implementation.

Comment: I get errors due to undeclared `uint8_t` (did you perhaps mean `std::uint8_t`?) but not to an ambiguous overload.  Perhaps you haven't shown us a complete example, and you have included `<stdio.h>`?  You'd be better writing the full name of `coolOS::common::printf` when you define it, instead of making your code fragile with `using namespace`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use

```
using namespace coolOS::common;

void printf(char* str){
    //printf implementation
}
```

it does not define the above `printf` in your namespace. It defines a global `printf` function, which is not what you want. Use the following to define them in your namespace.

```
namespace coolOS
{
   namespace common
   {
      void printf(char* str){
        //printf implementation
      }

      void printfHex(uint8_t key){
          char * msg = "00";
          //converts key and puts it in msg
          printf(msg);
      }
   }
}
```

---

If reducing a bit of typing is important to you, you can also use the following in the .cpp file:

```
namespace common = coolOS::common;

void common::printf(char* str){
    //printf implementation
}
void common::printfHex(int key){
    char * msg = "00";
    //converts key and puts it in msg
    printf(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake... I should have used coolsOS::common:: before the printf/printfHex deceleration.

```
coolOS::common::printf(char *str){ ...
```

I'm pretty new to c++ so i didn't know i have to do it when implementing functions